# Typo in Introduction to Commutative Algebra by Atiyah-Macdonald?

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, noetherian, dimension-theory-algebra

Proposition 11.4. Let $A$ be a Noetherian local ring, $m$ its maximal ideal, $q$ an $m$-primary ideal, $M$ a finitely generated $A$-module, ($M_n$) a stable $q$-filtration of $M$. Then

i) $M/M_n$ is of finite length, for each $n\geqslant0$;

ii) for all sufficiently large $n$ this length is a polynomial $g(n)$ of degree $\leqslant s$ in $n$, where $s$ is the least number of generators of $q$

iii) the degree and leading coefficient of

> $g(n)$ depend only on $M$ and $q$,

not on the chosen filtration.

> Aren't the degree and leading coefficient of $g(n)$ independent of the
>   choice of the primary ideal $q$ (meaning that we get the same degree and coefficient with another $m$-primary ideal $q'$)?

Comment: You'll get the same degree, but maybe not the same leading coefficient.

Comment: Possibly of interest is [Errata for Atiyah-Macdonald](https://mathoverflow.net/q/42241/15780).

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown Thank you very much for the clarification! I was wrong.